# REST API Not able to Post new customer

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am writing a Magento 2 REST API APP so far I can get a token, Update a SKU with PUT but I am not able to POST a new SKU or a new costumer. So far I understand that you update with PUT and create with POST. I followed several examples without luck.

I am testing with Postman.

Here is my HTTP:

```
POST 

/rest/V1/customers 
HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.2.153

Header
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer mfgsw0jtevp95ok1la99rysv0aqf9maj
Cache-Control: no-cache

Body:
{
  "customer": {
"email": "user@test.com",
"firstname": "name",
"lastname": "lastname",
"storeid": 1,
"websiteid": 1
  }
}
```

Answere:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log     file. Report ID: webapi-5ab75d4ddd21c"
```

}

exception.log

```
[2018-03-25 07:04:06] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5ab749e684459; Message: Property "Storeid" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface". {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5ab749e684459; Message: Property \"Storeid\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Customer\\Api\\Data\\CustomerInterface\". at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, LogicException(code: 0): Property \"Storeid\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Customer\\Api\\Data\\CustomerInterface\". at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was the Store ID.

So the code abouve works if you take out the line containing StoreID.

Comment: magento ver 1.9.2.3,I am work with REST API in POSTMAN, i have all oAuth 1.0 details like Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Token Secret. Now i moved to oAuth 2.0, how can i get my all oAuth 2.0 details? @Michael Müllerju Kasa